# Disparadores vs Procedimientos Almacenados

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, trigger

Luego de buscar en internet encontré varios tutoriales sobre el tema, pero lo que aún no me queda claro es cuando usar un disparador y cuando un procedimiento almacenado.

Muchas gracias por cualquier posible orientación!!!

Atentamente,

Miguel Angel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La principal diferencia entre los triggers y stored procedures: Es que los triggers son procedimientos que se ejecutan automáticamente, cuando se produce un evento sobre el que se quiere trabajar. Para esto existen tres tipos de eventos que pueden disparar un trigger: INSERT, DELETE y UPDATE. 
El trigger se programa para realizar una tarea determinada que se debe hacer siempre que se produzca uno de los eventos antes mencionados. No requiere intervención humana o programática y no se puede detener. 
Tiene algunas características:

1. No recibe parámetros de entrada o salida.
2. Los únicos valores de entrada son los correspondientes a los de las columnas que se insertan, y sólo son accesibles por medio de ciertas pseudovariables (NEW y OLD).
3. No se puede ejecutar una operación INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE sobre la misma tabla donde el TRIGGER se está ejecutando.
4. No se puede ejecutar una tarea sobre otra tabla, si la segunda tiene un trigger que afecte a la tabla del primer trigger en ejecución (circularidad).
5. No se puede invocar procedures desde un TRIGGER.
6. No se puede invocar un SELECT que devuelva una tabla resultado en el TRIGGER.
7. Otros

Un stored procedure es un procedimiento almacenado que debe ser invocado para ejecutarse.

1. Puede recibir parámetros y devolver parámetros.
2. Puede manejar cualquier tabla, realizar operaciones con ellas y realizar iteraciones de lectura/escritura.
3. Puede devolver una tabla como resultado.
   también valores dentro de los parámetros del prototipo si los mismos son también de salida.
4. Existen en la base donde se crean, pero no dependen de ninguna tabla.
5. Pueden aceptar recursividad (pero no es recomendable).
6. Otros

---–---------

En resumen si vas a realizar una auditoría de las tablas de tu base de datos utiliza triggers.
Si quieres utilizar procedimientos almacenados puede ser para sacar un listado de clientes. Esa acción será repetida en el sistema pero el trabajo lo realiza directamente la base de datos

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Un disparador (trigger en inglés) como su propio nombre dice se dispara cuando ocurre un evento en la base de datos, como un INSERT o un DELETE. Los disparadores se crean y no hace falta llamarlos para que se ejecuten, simplemente ellos se ejecutan con el requerimiento que tu has establecido. Por ejemplo haces un disparador (trigger) que cuando se haga un UPDATE en la base de datos en un campo, se ejecute el trigger y haga un INSERT en otra tabla con los valores viejos.

En cambio un procedimiento es como una función que creas y puedes llamar desde otro sitio para utilizarla como tu quieras. Puedes tener un procedimiento que te cuente las veces que aparece en nombre de los alumnos que les pasas por parámetro. Y cada vez que tú lo llames realizará eso. No se ejecuta solo como un disparador (trigger).

Espero haberte ayudado y haberme explicado bien. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!